# Mock CommonsMultipartFile in Grails integration test case

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

I have a service method which accepts CommonsMultipartFile and uploads it to server

```
class ExampleService() {
    def saveFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {
        // some validation code for file
    }
}
```

tried using both `MockMultipartHttpServletRequest` and `GrailsMockMultipartFile`.

In case of `MockMultipartHttpServletRequest` getting error as:

```
|  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: 
Cannot cast object 'org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile@2f39360' 
with class 'org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile' to 
class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile'
```

Same goes with `GrailsMockMultipartFile` getting error as:

```
|  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot 
cast object 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockMultipartFile@1022f0bd' 
with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockMultipartFile' to 
class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile'
```

referred this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910532/grails-spock-test-mock-commonsmultipartfile).

How should I mock `CommonsMultipartFile` and pass it as argument inside my test case ?

---

**Solution**

I found solution please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29642207/3143831)

Comment: Can you change the `saveFile()` method to use the interface `MultipartFile` rather than the specific implementation? If so, it should be easier to mock.

Comment: As @cjstehno says, always use interfaces where possible, e.g. `List` and `Map` instead of `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, and `MultipartFile` in this case. Only use implemtation class names when instantiating and when accessing methods that aren't in an interface

Comment: @cjstehno convert your comment to an answer so we can upvote it

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response guys. `saveFile()` method do some additional code other than saving a file. I don't want to change my existing method implementation.

Comment: @LaxmiSalunkhe - you would not be changing your implementation by using the interface. It would still be the same implementation passed in. If you code requires a specific implementation you might want to investigate refactoring to remove the specific dependency. That API is pretty robust without ever needing to use a specific implementation class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through different stack overflow links and `CommonsMultipartFile` JDK I come up with this solution

Please let me know if I am using wrong approach @burtbeckwith

```
File getTestFile(String fileName = "") {
    //Code which create file instance 
}

// Inside my test case I have created CommonsMultipartFile test file and used it.
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory()
FileItem fileItem = factory.createItem( "file", "multipart/form-data", false, "logo.png" )
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(getTestFile()), fileItem.getOutputStream())
CommonsMultipartFile testFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `saveFile(CommonsMultipartFile)` method to accept an instance of the interface `MultipartFile` rather than the specific implementation it will be easier to mock and you should lose no functionality.

```
saveFile(MultipartFile)
```